# Single line calculated property throws ParserError. Bug or not?

Tags: powershell

Have replicated this on two machines in both Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core 7.2.2, but seen no mention of it online. Is this a known bug, or should calculated properties simply not be written on a single line?

This fails with `Unexpected token 'expression=' in expression or statement.`

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object -Property Name, @{ label='FreeSpace' expression={($_.FreeSpace/1GB).ToString('F2')}}
```

Adding a carriage return before `expression=` prevents the ParserError

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object -Property Name, @{ label='FreeSpace'
expression={($_.FreeSpace/1GB).ToString('F2')}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a known bug

No

> should calculated properties simply not be written on a single line?

Sure, you just need an explicit *statement terminator* to separate the two key-value entries.

When you organize a hashtable literal (the `@{<key>="<value>"}` construct) with each key-value pair on separate lines, the *line breaks* act as implicit statement terminators.

Once you remove the line breaks, you need to use `;` in their place:

```
# this ...
@{
  Label = 'FreeSpace'
  Expression = { ... }
}

# ... becomes this
@{ Label = 'FreeSpace'; Expression = { ... } }
```